# URL automatically routing to default port

Tags: websphere

I am new to WebSphere. I have deployed one application on the WebSphere but when I call the application URL, it automatically adds ":9443" (default HHTPs port) in the server name and tries to call URL but due to that application doesn't work.
If removed the port number then application starts working.
Any suggestions, how I can fix it from WAS UI?

Thanks 
Nikhil

Comment: What version of WebSphere are you using?  Is this a WebSphere Liberty Profile server?

Answer (score 0):

For WebSphere Liberty, the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_virtual_hosts.html) covers this. In the server.xml, you will need to create a `<httpEndpoint>` element to open up a port and a `<virtualHost>` element specifying a `<hostAlias>`.

In either the `<webApplication>` element in your server.xml, or in your ibm-web-bnd.xml inside the application WAR, you will need to add a `<web-bnd>` element specifying the earlier virtualHost's name.

Example snippet inside server.xml

```
    <httpEndpoint id="appEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="3332" httpsPort="3333"/>
    <virtualHost id="someHost">
        <hostAlias>localhost:3333</hostAlias>
    </virtualHost>

    <webApplication name="app" location="{path.to.app.war}">
        <web-bnd>
            <virtual-host name="someHost" />
        </web-bnd>
    </webApplication>
```